# How to Detect the CCSprite Touchevent getBoundingbox equals of CCTouches

Tags: cocos2d-android

*I am new to COCOS2d. I am using ccsprite with animation as a button. Now i am struggle to detect the CCTouches and CCsprite getbounding box are equals for click event.*

Comment: Can You please elaborate what exactly are you trying to do. The question seem quite vague

Comment: I am using Menuitem with ccsprite. But i need Menuitem with animating spite.

Comment: you want to detect or need menuitem with animating sprite ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this way you can achieve what you need and write this code in CCtouches___() :

```
 ArrayList<CCSprite> animation= new ArrayList<CCSprite>();
 CGPoint  location = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY()));

 for (CCSprite target : animation){
     if(CGRect.containsPoint((target.getBoundingBox()), location)){
     //here what you want
     }
```